# salesforce mobile sdk create related object

Tags: rest, mobile, salesforce

I have `Sample_Product__c` custom object, and wanted to create object with relational field's external id:

```java
final Map<String, Object> prod = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prod.put("External_ID__c", obj.getString("medicineName"));

final Map < String, Object > sample = new HashMap < String, Object > ();

sample.put("Product__r", prod);
sample.put("LotNumber__c", obj.getString("medicineSerialNo"));
sample.put("GivenDate__c", format.format(givenDate));
sample.put("ExpiredDate__c", format.format(expireDate));
sample.put("GivenNumber__c", obj.getString("medicineQuantity"));
sample.put("Call__c", callid);

RestRequest.getRequestForCreate(getString(R.string.api_version), "Sample_Product__c", sample);
```

This gives error as, `Product__r should be SObject`...

In PHP, I was doing this like so:

```php
$sfobject = new stdclass();
$sfobject->External_ID__c = "...";
$sample->Product__r = $sfobject;
```

But have no idea how to achieve this with salesforce mobile SDK... hope someone knows, thanks!

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. What is the exact error message?  Perhaps you could add more code as well.

Comment: I am trying to create Custom Object "Call__c" which contains Product__c as relation, and Product__c has External_Id defined.

Comment: like here(Upserting Records and Associating with an External ID): http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#CSHID=resources_sobject_upsert.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fresources_sobject_upsert.htm|SkinName=webhelp